# Rounding exponential numbers results in ZERO

Tags: php

I am trying to round the numbers like below

```
$num =  6.91227556465E-8;
echo round($num);
```

This results in 0 . I tied adding (float) before  number , still I get zero , Expected result is 7.

Comment: Expected result is `0`. Or `0.00000007` with the right precision value. The result would never be the integer `7`.

Answer (score 2):

RTM: http://php.net/round

```
float round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] )
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You specified no precision, so a default of `0` decimal places is used, And since your number is actually

```
0.0000000691227etc...
```

you get 0 upon rounding, exactly as it should be.

```
php > echo round($num, 8);
7.0E-8
```

Note the extra parameter...

Comment: any shortcut to get 6.9 ? and then round it to 7 ?

Comment: @Vishnu `6.91227556465E-8` is `0.0000000691227556465`. In no universe does that round to `7`.

Comment: `round($num, 9) -> 6.9e-8`

Comment: how about getting first 3 letter from string ?

Comment: what string? You have floating point numbers. Those are **NOT** strings.